# Properly Attach Cabling To Joists

Tags: crawlspace, cabling, low-voltage

I am running cabling through my crawlspace roughly 40 feet.  I have the holes drilled, and am leaving about 25 feet extra looped off for contingency.  I am planning to attach the cabling to the joists to properly secure them, but not sure what the best option would be.  I know that a lot of the time, screw down clamps are used, however I feel that would be quite difficult in the tight space that I am in.

What other "safe" alternatives are there to properly secure the cabling to the floor joist in the crawl space?

Comment: What kind of cabling are you using? If it's already run through bored holes in joists, you normally don't need to secure it any further except at terminations...

Comment: Maybe I used the incorrect terminology.  It is Cat5 cable, and I am running it through the floor in one room, through the crawl space and up through the floor in another room.  I am just trying to figure out the best way to attach to the (what I am calling joists) in the crawlspace. And by joists I mean the supporting wood that makes a checker board for the floor on top of me to connect to.

Comment: Are you running the cable parallel to or perpendicular to the joists?

Comment: The cable runs perpendicular to the joists

Comment: And let me add that I have only drilled down from my home into the crawlspace, I have not drilled through anything else.  Just trying to fig out the best course of action for attaching the cabling to the wood beams in the crawlspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check with the NEC about low voltage wire being stored in damp locations as crawlspaces have the potential of being damp.

Personally, I would secure the Cat5e in a long oval loop between the floor joists under the location where it is going to AFTER finishing the install inside. See my lovely diagram...

[image: A truly lovely drawing]

I would secure the wire to the joists using these types of clamps / hooks to allow for future renovations.

[image: Plastic Conduit Clamp]

[image: Metal Conduit hook]

Comment: Drilling through the joists. Just a hole large enough to fit the ethernet through. 1 inch should be larger than what's needed, but would allow for future lines added.

Answer (score 3):

There are staplers meant for wiring that are great for situations where you don't have too much room for a screwdriver or to swing a hammer. The Arrow T25 is one model, but there are other options out there.

Just do a search for Cat5 stapler and you should find lot of options. Make sure you pay attention to the instructions and use the right staples or else you could accidentally cut one or more of the conductors in your cable.

Another method is to staple a zip tie to the joist and then fasten it around the Cat5.

Answer (score -2):

I know nothing about electrical, but structurally (and I know it's too late to change the holes you've already drilled, but maybe for future reference,) never drill in the middle one-third span of a joist. Also, in the other two-third sections, drill  as close to the middle of the height of the joist...that is not in the top compression side nor the bottom tension side. Also, if possible don't drill within the height of the beam/joist where it bears on the wall. That is to say, if the beam/joist is 8" high, then don't drill within 8" of the bearing wall. AND in no event should the hole be 1/6th the height of the beam/joist....just rule-of-thumb...

Comment: Good information, but not an answer. Should've probably been a comment.